# fetching Data to ng-bootstrap table in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

**Hi Every one here
I face problem with fetching data to array but when I put data to array the editor said not defined array**

**Error Message:**
Failed to compile.

src/app/customers/customers-list/customers-list.component.ts:111:14 - error TS2551: Property 'CUSTOMERS' does not exist on type 'CustomersListComponent'. Did you mean 'customers$'?

111         this.CUSTOMERS = posts;
~~~~~~~~~

src/app/customers/customers-list/customers-list.component.ts:64:3
64   customers$: Observable<Customer[]>;
~~~~~~~~~~
'customers$' is declared here.

**This is the CODE**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  PipeTransform, // table
} from '@angular/core';

import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'; // table
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'; // table

import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; // table
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators'; // table
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; // modal
import {AddCustomerComponent} from '../add-customer/add-customer.component'; // modal


import { faFolderPlus, faPencilAlt, faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; // fontawsome icons
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

// table
interface Customer {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  company: string;
  remaining: number;
  email: string;
  mobile: number;
  whats_up: number;

}

let CUSTOMERS: Customer[] = [
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'jack',
    company: 'SDTE',
    remaining: 580,
    email: 'test@test.com',
    mobile: +456456456456,
    whats_up: +456456456
  }
];

function search(text: string, pipe: PipeTransform): Customer[] {
  return CUSTOMERS.filter(customer => {
    const term = text.toLowerCase();
    return customer.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
      || customer.company.toLowerCase().includes(term)
      || pipe.transform(customer.remaining).includes(term)
      || customer.email.toLowerCase().includes(term)
      || pipe.transform(customer.mobile).includes(term)
      || pipe.transform(customer.whats_up).includes(term);
  });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.css'],
  providers: [DecimalPipe] // table
})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

  // table
  customers$: Observable<Customer[]>;
  filter = new FormControl('');

  faFolderPlus = faFolderPlus;
  faPencilAlt = faPencilAlt;
  faTrashAlt = faTrashAlt;



  constructor(
    pipe: DecimalPipe, // table
    private modalService: NgbModal, // modal
    private http: HttpClient // Get All Data
) {
    // table
    this.customers$ = this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(text => search(text, pipe))
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllData();
  }

  // modal
  openPopupModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddCustomerComponent,{ centered: true, size: 'lg' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }

  private getAllData() {
  this.http
    .get('http://localhost:3000/customers')
    .subscribe(
      posts => {
        console.log('GET all Data works');
        this.CUSTOMERS = posts;    // <<<<< Here is the problem ************ How can I to Fix it.

      });
  }
}
```

I

Answer (score 0):

`this.CUSTOMERS = posts;` this refers to current class `CustomersListComponent` but your variable is outside the class so you need to assign directly `CUSTOMERS = posts;` :)

Comment: I try this, but Not working
```
 error TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to us
e the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Customer[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

111         CUSTOMERS = posts;
            ~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: if you suggest any way to make it all table and data to be in the calss to orgnize the code tell me

Comment: [
  {
    "customer_id": "1",
    "name": "qq",
    "branch": null,
    "company": null,
    "mobile": null,
    "whats_up": "141",
    "email": null,
    "vat_id": null,
    "motawin": true,
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T21:00:00.000Z"
  }
]

This what I get from server Object

How can I change it to array

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the return type.

You could try using this:

```
 private getAllData() {
  this.http
    .get<Customer[]>('http://localhost:3000/customers') // <<<<< Try using this. 
    .subscribe(
      posts => {
        console.log('GET all Data works');
        CUSTOMERS = posts;
      });
  }
```

Comment: It does not work. I search alot the problem how can I translate the object data that came from server to array?

Comment: [
  {
    "customer_id": "1",
    "name": "qq",
    "branch": null,
    "company": null,
    "mobile": null,
    "whats_up": "141",
    "email": null,
    "vat_id": null,
    "motawin": true,
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T21:00:00.000Z"
  }
]

This what I get from server Object

How can I change it to array

Comment: Which error message do you have now? The part you commented is an array so you don't need to change it to an array. I reproduced it. For me it's working. If you want to add it to the array you can use CUSTOMERS.push(posts); instead of CUSTOMERS = posts;